# How to pause and play music with AVPlayer in Swift in other view

Tags: swift, xcode, avplayer, tvos

I have 2 views. One with a list of music and one ”music player view”. I am using the below code to pause and play music in the ”music player view”.

I also want to pause and play music in the first view with the list of music. But when I add the below code to the first view and press pause/play button the music pauses and then starts playing directly.

```
override func pressesEnded(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    presses.forEach { press in
        switch press.type {
        case .playPause:
            if player.isPlaying {
                player.pause()
            }
            else {
                player.play()
            }
        default: break
        }
    }

}
```

I want the music to pause if the music is playing and play if it’s not playing, in both views.

Comment: show where you declare your `avplayer` object?

Comment: I am using FRadioPlayer that is a wrapper around AVPlayer to handle internet radio playback. I just use this:     let player = FRadioPlayer.shared And in viewdidload in the ”music player view”:         
        player.delegate = self    
        And
        player.radioURL = URL(string: radiostationUrl)!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through all the set of presses, just get the first touch like below
`

```
override func pressesEnded(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
 guard let press = presses.first else { return }
        switch press.type {
        case .playPause:
            if player.isPlaying {
                player.pause()
            }
            else {
                player.play()
            }
        default: break
        }
    }

}
```

But for your second problem you need to provide more information.

Comment: The code works good. The problem is when I go to ”play music view” and press pause the music paues and then starts directly. But when I go back to the start view the pause/play button works perfectly in both views. It is just problem the first time I press pause/play button.